# android audiorecord failing thinks there are multiple instances

Tags: android, audiorecord

Using the following code I am opening audiorecord, reading, closing and reopening essentially forever (as audiorecord is limited to reading 2^32 shorts of data it seems and I want it to run and processing forever)

```
  loop the following {

    AudioRecord recorder = null;
    int N = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC,44100,
                                                     AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                                     AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                                     N*10);
    recorder.startRecording();


    //read and do some processing

    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();

  }
```

This works fine about 1200 times until I get the error

E/AudioHardwareMSM76XXA(  122): More than one instance of recording not supported

which is what you would get if you tried to open an already open recording instance.

Is it possible that the code continues with recorder.release() in the background and occasionally it hasn't finished before opening the new instance?

Thanks

R

Comment: it smells like somekind of out of memory error or something, not sure. You should try to instantiate the recorder once and re-use it.

Comment: So you are saying that if you just keep calling the read method, it will eventually fail to obtain data?  I'm estimating that would take about 27 hours to reach 2^32, but am probably off by a factor of two in one director or another.  What I'm really not understanding is how you managed to test your app for 1200 trials * 27 hours...

Comment: fonZ - you mean just put "AudioRecord recorder = null;" before the loop?

Comment: Chris - if I keep reading a single open instance of audiorecord, it fails after 2^32 reads - 27 hours at 44.1 kHz.  So I am opening, closing, opening etc repeatedly in a loop.  opening takes about 100ms but I dont lose important data.  after 1200 or so of these, I get the error about trying to open an already open channel.  I am opening and closing about every 5 seconds.  I could do 24 hours, but I want to know why the error happens because it will happen eventually and I want the app and audiorecord to work essentially permanently (as a voltmeter)

Comment: That it happens sounds like a platform bug, hopefully in this specific Android version.  It'd think it would be far wiser to handle it by only cycling every few hours.  And then you should be able to catch the exception and retry.  Do you really need such a high sample rate?  Surely you aren't keeping gigabytes of data around, so you must be processing it down, and unless you are capturing (or expecting) high frequency content you probably don't.  Personally I'd be more worried about keeping the process alive that long.

Comment: 44.1 kHz seems to be the one that all microphones/phone support, so I am using this.  I average down to 441 Hz every 100 samples.  I send up to the web some analytics every 5 seconds or so very little data saved.  I'll open and close recorder every few hours or a day finally, but I'd still like to work out this bug, so am keeping at 5 seconds or 1 second until I can solve it.  If I can't I'll just make it longer and expect it to fail occasionally.  Why would you be worried about keeping the process alive that long?  What is likely to kill it?

Comment: Android is not designed to keep things running for hours on end with no user interaction - on the contrary, it's designed to kill off background things to preserve the user experience.  Granted, if there is no user that may be less likely to occur, but still, it's not designed or tested for server-like usage.  Given your reports are 5 seconds apart, I really don't see why you can't handle the exception when it occurs, and then (after you test that) make it so it will only happen every 27 hours or multiple thereof.

Comment: thanks for info Chris.  Yes, I'll try and handle error but loop every 24 hours or so after that.  there will be no user - I'm using phone as environmental monitor.